# Usage of “how is everyone”

Tags: salutations

When we ask about well-being when we meet other people, is this the correct usage:

> How is everyone at home?

or are there any other ways to address this when talking to a person via email or face-to-face?

Answer (score 2):

*How is everyone at home?* is a polite, acceptable way to ask about how the other person's family and household is doing. You could also ask directly:

> How is your family?

Answer (score 1):

Informally, "How is everyone?" works fine if you're familiar enough with the person's family as not to require clarification.

Answer (score 0):

`How is everyone at home?` is just fine, though there are a few other ways of putting it:

For example, `How is everyone holding up?` which is more informal, and friendlier.

Also, in informal/spoken english, people usually reduce the `How is` to `How's`.

Answer (score 0):

What is often used is something like:

> How are you and yours?

The 'yours' refers to the recipient's family and/or other concerns.  It leaves the decision of whom to write about to the recipient, who can then respond with any news regarding anyone they find of interest.

This is typically used most frequently in non-conversational exchanges (text messages, snail mail, email, etc.) but not so often in live conversation.